# Importing data from (large) file Excel to datagridview and then database - why inserting to database takes so long and doesn't save all data?

Tags: c#, mysql, excel, datetime, large-data

In this case I import data from large file (which is about 37 MB) to datagridview. The table from Excel file is in below:
[image]

After loading data from Excel to datagridview I'm inserting that data to MySQL database:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagrdStatus_order.Rows)
{
    string constring = "datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = ";
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT IGNORE INTO try1.order_status(ID_WORKER, ID_ORDER, ID_MODULE, ID_PROJECT, AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE) SELECT workers.ID_WORKER, orders.ID_ORDER, module.ID_MODULE, projects.ID, @AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, @BEGIN_DATE, @END_DATE FROM try1.workers INNER JOIN try1.orders INNER JOIN try1.modules INNER JOIN try1.projects WHERE workers.FNAME = @FNAME AND workers.LNAME = @LNAME AND workers.ID_WORKER = @ID_WORKER AND orders.DESC_ORDER = @DESC_ORDER AND orders.ORDER_NUMBER = @ORDER_NUMBER AND modules.NAME = @MODULES_NAME AND projects.PROJECT_NAME = @PROJECT_NAME", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_WORKER", row.Cells["ID_WORKER"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FNAME", row.Cells["FNAME"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LNAME", row.Cells["LNAME"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESC_ORDER", row.Cells["DESC_ORDER"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ORDER_NUMBER", row.Cells["ORDER_NUMBER"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODULES_NAME", row.Cells["NAME"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROJECT_NAME", row.Cells["PROJECT_NAME"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS", row.Cells["AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEGIN_DATE", row.Cells["BEGIN_DATE"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END_DATE", row.Cells["END_DATE"].Value);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Later when I executing this importing code, that problem is began.

1. Despite of switching off ContextSwitchDeadlock exception (of only 1 table to insert) inserting this data takes about... 10 minutes.
2. Despite of not calling any error or exception in program it inserts not all data. In that case I saw I have imported only 8 statuses not all (11 statuses).

And I have a question: why inserting to database takes so long and doesn't save all data? How to reduce inserting data to MySQL db and save all data?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ControlDataBase
{
    public partial class New_Tables : Form
    {
        public New_Tables()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Form1 frm1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void ImportData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Files|*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xlsb;*.xltx;*.xltm;*.xls;*.xlt;*.xls;*.xml;*.xml;*.xlam;*.xla;*.xlw;*.xlr;", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(ofd.FileName);
                    string FileName1 = ofd.FileName;

                    string excel = fi.FullName;

                    if (ofd.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                    {
                        StrConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;\"";
                    }

                    if (ofd.FileName.EndsWith(".xls"))
                    {
                        StrConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 1.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
                    }
                    OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(StrConn);

                    OleDbDataAdapter dta5 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Order_status$]", oledbconn);
                    oledbconn.Open();

                    DataSet dsole5 = new DataSet();
                    dta5.Fill(dsole5, "Order_status$");
                    datagrdStatus_order.DataSource = dsole5.Tables["Order_status$"];

                    oledbconn.Close();

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagrdStatus_order.Rows)
{
    string constring = "datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = ";
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT IGNORE INTO try1.order_status(ID_WORKER, ID_ORDER, ID_MODULE, ID_PROJECT, AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE) SELECT workers.ID_WORKER, orders.ID_ORDER, module.ID_MODULE, projects.ID, @AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, @BEGIN_DATE, @END_DATE FROM try1.workers INNER JOIN try1.orders INNER JOIN try1.modules INNER JOIN try1.projects WHERE workers.FNAME = @FNAME AND workers.LNAME = @LNAME AND workers.ID_WORKER = @ID_WORKER AND orders.DESC_ORDER = @DESC_ORDER AND orders.ORDER_NUMBER = @ORDER_NUMBER AND modules.NAME = @MODULES_NAME AND projects.PROJECT_NAME = @PROJECT_NAME", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_WORKER", row.Cells["ID_WORKER"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FNAME", row.Cells["FNAME"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LNAME", row.Cells["LNAME"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESC_ORDER", row.Cells["DESC_ORDER"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ORDER_NUMBER", row.Cells["ORDER_NUMBER"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODULES_NAME", row.Cells["NAME"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROJECT_NAME", row.Cells["PROJECT_NAME"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS", row.Cells["AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEGIN_DATE", row.Cells["BEGIN_DATE"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END_DATE", row.Cells["END_DATE"].Value);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
                    connection.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("The data are imported correctly");

                    loaddataalldatagridview();
                }
            }
        }

        private void loaddataalldatagridview()
        {
            frm1.loaddata5();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've modified the lines of code which are base on @Matt_Johnson answer:

1) in for loop:

```
            string constring = "datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = ";
            string query5 = "INSERT IGNORE INTO try1.order_status(ID_WORKER, ID_ORDER, ID_MODULE, ID_PROJECT, AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE) SELECT workers.ID_WORKER, orders.ID_ORDER, module.ID_MODULE, projects.ID, @AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, @BEGIN_DATE, @END_DATE FROM try1.workers INNER JOIN try1.orders INNER JOIN try1.modules INNER JOIN try1.projects WHERE workers.FNAME = @FNAME AND workers.LNAME = @LNAME AND workers.ID_WORKER = @ID_WORKER AND orders.DESC_ORDER = @DESC_ORDER AND orders.ORDER_NUMBER = @ORDER_NUMBER AND modules.NAME = @MODULES_NAME AND projects.PROJECT_NAME = @PROJECT_NAME";

            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query5, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID_WORKER", MySqlDbType.Int32);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FNAME", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LNAME", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DESC_ORDER", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ORDER_NUMBER", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MODULES_NAME", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PROJECT_NAME", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS", MySqlDbType.Int32);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@BEGIN_DATE", MySqlDbType.DateTime);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@END_DATE", MySqlDbType.DateTime);
                    con.Open();

                    for (int i = 0; i < datagrdStatus_order.Rows.Count + 1; i++)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters["@ID_WORKER"].Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                        cmd.Parameters["@FNAME"].Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
                        cmd.Parameters["@LNAME"].Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
                        cmd.Parameters["@DESC_ORDER"].Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value;
                        cmd.Parameters["@ORDER_NUMBER"].Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value;
                        cmd.Parameters["@MODULES_NAME"].Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value;
                        cmd.Parameters["@PROJECT_NAME"].Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value;
                        cmd.Parameters["@AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS"].Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value;
                        cmd.Parameters["@BEGIN_DATE"].Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value;
                        cmd.Parameters["@END_DATE"].Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Imported correctly");
            loaddataalldatagridview();
```

2) in foreach loop:

```
            string constring = "datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = ";
            string query5 = "INSERT IGNORE INTO try1.order_status(ID_WORKER, ID_ORDER, ID_MODULE, ID_PROJECT, AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE) SELECT workers.ID_WORKER, orders.ID_ORDER, module.ID_MODULE, projects.ID, @AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, @BEGIN_DATE, @END_DATE FROM try1.workers INNER JOIN try1.orders INNER JOIN try1.modules INNER JOIN try1.projects WHERE workers.FNAME = @FNAME AND workers.LNAME = @LNAME AND workers.ID_WORKER = @ID_WORKER AND orders.DESC_ORDER = @DESC_ORDER AND orders.ORDER_NUMBER = @ORDER_NUMBER AND modules.NAME = @MODULES_NAME AND projects.PROJECT_NAME = @PROJECT_NAME";

            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query5, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID_WORKER", MySqlDbType.Int32);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FNAME", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LNAME", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DESC_ORDER", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ORDER_NUMBER", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MODULES_NAME", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PROJECT_NAME", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS", MySqlDbType.Int32);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@BEGIN_DATE", MySqlDbType.DateTime);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@END_DATE", MySqlDbType.DateTime);
                    con.Open();

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagrdStatus_order.Rows)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_WORKER", row.Cells["ID_WORKER"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FNAME", row.Cells["FNAME"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LNAME", row.Cells["LNAME"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESC_ORDER", row.Cells["DESC_ORDER"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ORDER_NUMBER", row.Cells["ORDER_NUMBER"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODULES_NAME", row.Cells["NAME"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROJECT_NAME", row.Cells["PROJECT_NAME"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS", row.Cells["AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEGIN_DATE", row.Cells["BEGIN_DATE"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END_DATE", row.Cells["END_DATE"].Value);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Imported correctly");
            loaddataalldatagridview();
```

And I have still not effective answer. I send a link to shared file to download:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LE7phZwyT7VR3NJc6bA-n1reCJ_-X3u9/view?usp=sharing

Maybe it helps.

Comment: Some suggestions. Batch the inserts instead of doing each one at a time. Take advantage of async-await in the event handler. Use Transactions. Use one connection instead or using and disposing it for each row.

Comment: Probably too big. Try paging the GET and chunking/batching the insert/update.

Comment: You need to import your Excel data in to a DataTable. The DataGridView can then be bound to the DataTable, showing the results and allowing direct editing. The DataTable can be used to quickly update the MySql table. Just like their names imply: A DataGridView is a view object to be used for views. A DataTable  is for holding the actual data and it is a database object. They have their own strengths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things that stand out to me when looking at your code that would affect performance:

- `AddWithValue` is expensive because it uses reflection, and sometimes it does the wrong thing.  Instead, add the parameters using their names and data types, without providing values.  Then later, supply the values as needed.
- You are connecting and disconnecting to the database for each row.  This is *very* expensive in terms of network resources.  Instead, you should connect to the database once, then execute your commands, then close the connection.  You can even re-use the command and simply vary the parameters for each row.

  ```
  using (MySqlConnection con ...)
  {
      using (MySqlCommand cmd ...)
      {
          ... define the parameters and add them to the command, 
          ... without adding values to them yet

          con.Open();
          foreach (...)
          {
              ... now set values of the parameters for the row

              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }

          con.Close();
      }
  }
  ```

Note, I deliberately did not provide full code, as much of this is already available in other Stack Overflow answers, external web sites, and product documentation.  I think if you try, you should be able to complete the puzzle.  Good luck.

Comment: It looks a brilliant idea but i've tried with defining parameters like cmd.Parameters.Add(...); then i executed  that code with foreach and for loop too. I have still the same effect. See please my edited question (I've just added the link to it). Maybe it helps.

Comment: Please edit your question again to show the updated code.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok i've just edited question. I added lines of code in 'EDIT' section. What do you think?

Comment: Hmmm.. the for-loop example looks ok at first glance.  The for-each example is still calling `AddWithValue` though.   How are the results affected?  You might consider using the parameter index (`cmd.Parameters[0].Value` instead of `cmd.Parameters["@ID_WORKER"].Value`) to save the cost of the lookup.

Comment: Also something up with the index.  You go from 0 to < Count+1, which is odd.  Either 0 to < Count, or if you're offset by a row then 1 to <= Count.

Comment: As far as why not all data imported, `INSERT IGNORE` deliberately ignores any errors.  If you remove `IGNORE` and watch for failures, then you'll figure out which rows are causing the problems and why.

Comment: To figure out which rows are causing failures i have to insert a breakpoints, right?

Comment: Breakpoints aren't going to be useful, but if you remove `IGNORE`, then an exception will be thrown when an insert failure occurs.  If you run in VS in debug mode, it will stop on its own if you aren't catching those exceptions elsewhere.  (You could always add your own try/catch block around this code and log the exception in any way you please.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195604/discussion-between-prochu1991-and-matt-johnson).

Answer (score 2):

1. Export as a CSV file.
2. Import via `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ...`

Both steps are very fast.  No "code" needed unless you need to manipulate the format of a column.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code. You are probably reaching the max sessions because of how you are opening and closing the SQL connection on every row, like @Nkosi says above.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ControlDataBase
{
    public partial class New_Tables : Form
    {
        public New_Tables()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Form1 frm1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void ImportData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Files|*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xlsb;*.xltx;*.xltm;*.xls;*.xlt;*.xls;*.xml;*.xml;*.xlam;*.xla;*.xlw;*.xlr;", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(ofd.FileName);
                    string FileName1 = ofd.FileName;

                    string excel = fi.FullName;

                    if (ofd.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                    {
                        StrConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;\"";
                    }

                    if (ofd.FileName.EndsWith(".xls"))
                    {
                        StrConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 1.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
                    }
                    OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(StrConn);

                    OleDbDataAdapter dta5 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Order_status$]", oledbconn);
                    oledbconn.Open();

                    DataSet dsole5 = new DataSet();
                    dta5.Fill(dsole5, "Order_status$");
                    datagrdStatus_order.DataSource = dsole5.Tables["Order_status$"];

                    oledbconn.Close();
        string constring = "datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = ";
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring))
        {

con.Open();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagrdStatus_order.Rows)
{

        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT IGNORE INTO try1.order_status(ID_WORKER, ID_ORDER, ID_MODULE, ID_PROJECT, AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE) SELECT workers.ID_WORKER, orders.ID_ORDER, module.ID_MODULE, projects.ID, @AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, @BEGIN_DATE, @END_DATE FROM try1.workers INNER JOIN try1.orders INNER JOIN try1.modules INNER JOIN try1.projects WHERE workers.FNAME = @FNAME AND workers.LNAME = @LNAME AND workers.ID_WORKER = @ID_WORKER AND orders.DESC_ORDER = @DESC_ORDER AND orders.ORDER_NUMBER = @ORDER_NUMBER AND modules.NAME = @MODULES_NAME AND projects.PROJECT_NAME = @PROJECT_NAME", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_WORKER", row.Cells["ID_WORKER"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FNAME", row.Cells["FNAME"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LNAME", row.Cells["LNAME"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESC_ORDER", row.Cells["DESC_ORDER"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ORDER_NUMBER", row.Cells["ORDER_NUMBER"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODULES_NAME", row.Cells["NAME"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROJECT_NAME", row.Cells["PROJECT_NAME"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS", row.Cells["AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEGIN_DATE", row.Cells["BEGIN_DATE"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END_DATE", row.Cells["END_DATE"].Value);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
con.Close();
}
                    connection.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("The data are imported correctly");

                    loaddataalldatagridview();
                }
            }
        }

        private void loaddataalldatagridview()
        {
            frm1.loaddata5();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, batch inserts are definitely worth looking into. Unless there is a reason that you want to insert each individually.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But it haven't helped enough. I've the same effect as before that change.  I have still the same effect. See please my edited question (I've just added the link to it). Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try Excel to database and then bind to datagrid view from sql.
Datagridview takes more memory and converting back to sql database takes time too.